# jQuery - Hide primary ul once submenu is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, menu

I have this jQuery script which outputs a HTML menu from a json tree.

```
$(function () {

    var data = {
        menu: [{
            name: 'Croatia',
            link: '0',
            sub: null
        }, {
            name: 'England',
            link: '1',
            sub: [{
                name: 'Arsenal',
                link: '0-0',
                sub: null
            }, {
                name: 'Liverpool',
                link: '0-1',
                sub: null
            }, {
                name: 'Manchester United',
                link: '0-2',
                sub: null
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Spain',
            link: '2',
            sub: [{
                name: 'Barcelona',
                link: '2-0',
                sub: null
            }, {
                name: 'Real Madrid',
                link: '2-1',
                sub: null
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Germany',
            link: '3',
            sub: [{
                name: 'Bayern Munich',
                link: '3-1',
                sub: null
            }, {
                name: 'Borrusia Dortmund',
                link: '3-2',
                sub: null
            }]
        }]
    };
    var getMenuItem = function (itemData) {
        var item = $("<li>")
            .append(
        $("<a>", {
            href: '#' + itemData.link,
            html: itemData.name
        }));
        if (itemData.sub) {
            var subList = $("<ul>");
            $.each(itemData.sub, function () {
                subList.append(getMenuItem(this));
            });
            item.append(subList);
        }
        return item;
    };

    var $menu = $("#menu");
    $.each(data.menu, function () {
        $menu.append(
            getMenuItem(this)
        );
    });
    $menu.menu();
});
```

And HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<ul id="menu"></ul>
```

That does the job, it outputs the HTML menu, but I want the submenu's to be hidden until the visitor clicks on it.

So to clear it up, we take this menu for example:

```
Primary Menu 1
    - Submenu item 1
    - Submenu item 1

Primary Menu 2
    - Submenu item 2
    - Submenu item 2
```

Once the visitor clicks on "Primary Menu 1", it should hide all the primary menu's and only display the submenu items.

How can I archieve this outcome?

---

Update; managed to get it working correctly (json is also loaded in a different file now.)

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(function () {
        var getMenuItem = function (itemData) {
            var item = $("<li>")
                .append(
            $("<a>", {
                href: '#' + itemData.link,
                html: itemData.name
            }));
            if (itemData.sub) {
                var subList = $('<ul>', {'class':'sub-menu'});
                $.each(itemData.sub, function () {
                    subList.append(getMenuItem(this));
                });
                item.append(subList);
            }
            return item;
        };

        var $menu = $("#menu");
        $.each(data.menu, function () {
            $menu.append(
                getMenuItem(this)
            );
        });

        $(".sub-menu").hide();

        $("li").click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after all your menu creation code, you would want to start by adding a class to all menu items that have submenus. You can do that in your creation code.

```
var subList = $('<ul>', {'class':'sub-menu'});
```

From there you should be able to know what menu items have submenus, you can do various things from there.

One example could be to give the `sub-menu` a default height of `0` in css. Then add click events to your `<ul class="sub-menu">` parent `<li>` to animate the menu height, while adding a class to the `<li>` know when it's open or closed.

```
$('.sub-menu').parent().on('click', function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
   if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
     $(this).children('.sub-menu').animate({'height':'auto');
   } else {
     $(this).children('.sub-menu').animate({'height':'0');
   }
});
```

You can even take that a step further and do a check against ALL your menu items that have submenus, to make sure if a previously opened one gets closed before the new one is opened.

```
//Inside the previous click handler as the 1st thing in it.
$(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
```

Not 100% if that code will work in your situation (depending on existing styling) but it should provide you with the idea you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. Like you said, it does not fully work but I'll get it working, this is a good kickstarter!

Comment: No Problem! Yea sorry the code didn't work for you but I saw the question as more 'conceptual' rather than a coding issue. I knew at least this would get you on right track :)